# Watch connectivity session issues

Tags: ios, swift, apple-watch, watchconnectivity, apple-watch-complication

I am trying to send a message from a watch extension to the phone in order to update a complication.

AppDelegate.swift

```
var session = WCSession.defaultSession()

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        if WCSession.isSupported(){
            session.delegate = self
            session.activateSession()
        }
        return true
}

func session(session: WCSession, didReceiveMessage message: [String : AnyObject], replyHandler: ([String : AnyObject]) -> Void) {
        replyHandler(["scheduleNames":scheduleNames, "scheduleData":scheduleData])
    }
```

ExtensionDelegate.swift

```
override init(){
    super.init()
    if WCSession.isSupported(){
        session = WCSession.defaultSession()
        session.delegate = self
        session.activateSession()
    }
    self.sendMessage()
}

func sendMessage(){
        print("Attempting to send message")
        session.sendMessage(["Sender": "Complication"], replyHandler: {
            reply in
            print(reply.description)
            }, errorHandler: {
                error in
                print(error.description)
        })

    }
```

But when I run the watch simulator (and the phone app is not open), I receive

> Error Domain=WCErrorDomain Code=7007 "WatchConnectivity session on paired device is not reachable."

This also comes on the physical phone and watch.

What could be causing this?

UPDATE

This only happens when I make the call from the extension.  The watch app can send and receive the message fine.  Also, it works when called from applicationDidFinishLaunching() but not anything else in the extension delegate.

UPDATE

 
I fixed the previous and now get

> WatchConnectivity session has no delegate.

Comment: Is the problem now that you are getting a "no delegate" or "not reachable" error?

Comment: It went between both.  However, I have figured out the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36961904/3576234), I figured out the issue.  Calling from the Complication (which is what I was doing) in the requestedUpdateDidBegin() executes an asynchronous method *in* an asynchronous method, resulting in the update function ending before the sendMessage function returns.